# Flutter audio call output

Tags: flutter, audio, call, sip

I have a working flutter app which make calls using sip and i want to add a button to switch between the speaker and the earpiece. Unfortunately I found nothing on that specific topic after searching a few hours. No flutter packages seems to do it so I hope someone here can help me to find a way to do it if it's even possible.
Thanks.

I tried to find flutter packages, informations on the internet or youtube but i didn't find any implementation of that. My need is specific cause the call is being handled by sip so the audio output is the default one I think.